# SharePoint FormField not rendering

Tags: visual-studio-2012, office365-apps, hosted-app

I have had an app targeted for SharePoint online which provisions a few custom lists and custom list forms that has been, and continues to work on my work Office 365 team site.

I made some changes to the app and on my developer account, references like:

```
  <SharePoint:FormField  runat="server"  ID="FieldId"  ControlMode="New" FieldName="FieldName"  />
```

are not rendering at all on custom list pages, aside from one list, whose custom pages oddly appear to continue functioning.

I have been pulling my hair trying to figure the source of this for hours not to no end. I have even created an app that does nothing but provision a list and a custom form and on deployment to my developer account, form fields do not render (the HTML rendered on visiting these forms is something like this:

```
<span id='WPQ1f257f1df-1870-4fef-a590-4f29baa6e99bIPName' data-sp-control='SPFieldText' data-sp-options='{&quot;mode&quot;:3,&quot;source&quot;:&quot;IPName&quot;}'></span>
```

without the html input controls as it happens on the working form.

Hoping there is someone in here who may have ideas as to what could be the cause of this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you ever find out a solution please? I have a sharepoint hosted add in that is suddenly no longer working in a client site...

Comment: No Rahma. Nox fix just yet.